# How to rank arrays by most contained to less using && operator postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am looking to rank my arrays from highest match to lowest match with the overlaps operator `&&` so something like,

```
SELECT tags 
FROM users, **rank here AS rank** 
WHERE users.tags && query 
ORDER BY rank DESC;
```

I was then hoping to be able to merge this some how to my ts_rank results from full text search if this is possible? I wasn't sure if `rank()` function was going to help me.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Expected results would be something like doing this first getting a float value from full-text-seach in a complete different column;

```
SELECT 
    content, ts_rank(to_tsvector(content), query) AS rank 
FROM 
    microposts, 
    plainto_tsquery('dc comics') query 
WHERE 
    microposts.content @@ query 
ORDER BY 
    rank DESC;
```

Which would give something along the lines of;

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════╤═══════════╗
║ content                                         │ rank      ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════╪═══════════╣
║ dc comics dc comics dc comics dc comics         │ 0.986064  ║
╟─────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ dc comics dc comics dc comics                   │ 0,911679  ║
╟─────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ dc comics dc comics dc comics went to the beach │ 0.603393  ║
╟─────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ dc comics dc comics went to the beach\r         │ 0.340005  ║
╟─────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║                                                 │           ║
╟─────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ went to the beach. dc comics                    │ 0.0991032 ║
╟─────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ It was great. went to the beach dc comics       │ 0.0991932 ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════╧═══════════╝
```

Then doing a tag ranking based on the most matched first with code like this without a ranking;

```
SELECT tags 
FROM users 
WHERE users.tags && ARRAY['chicken', 'cat', 'apple', 'monkey'];
```

And expecting something like;

```
╔═══════════════════════════════╤══════╗
║ tags                          │ rank ║
╠═══════════════════════════════╪══════╣
║ {chicken, cat, apple, monkey} │ 4    ║
╟───────────────────────────────┼──────╢
║ {chicken, cat, apple}         │ 3    ║
╟───────────────────────────────┼──────╢
║ {chicken, cat}                │ 2    ║
╟───────────────────────────────┼──────╢
║ {chicken}                     │ 1    ║
╚═══════════════════════════════╧══════╝
```

But as I posted if I had rankings like this and tried to add them to each other I may get mixed results as I am doing more than just 1 full-text-search and adding results so I get a nice balanced result there but if I add numbers like 4 or 5 from from a tag search then that single search on that column when added to say a really low ranked full text search will trump the rest giving a record back that matches all or most tags but is low in regards to the other searches.

**Update** I think the best thing to do here would be simply use the `@>` contains method for strict search and perhaps a lazy search using `&&`.

Comment: I now realise this may be combining to many variables giving unexpected results, especially if I am combining lexeme values to some other ratio

Comment: I edited my question.